# How can I select the 2nd td using Xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Using below below I am able to locate the 1st td. However, I'm unable to locate the 2nd td using xpath? can you please help here?

Below code works correct for 1st TD -

```
WebElement SuperElement = (WebElement) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", parentElement);
        return SuperElement.findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText();
```

Below code I need 2 td but doesn't work -

```
WebElement SuperElement = (WebElement) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", parentElement);
        return SuperElement.findElement(By.xpath("/td[2]")).getText();
```

Comment: can you share the relevant hTML?

Comment: `findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(1).getText()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting XPath with `/` always makes the XPath absolute i.e relative to the document node. You should start with `./` or just remove the `/` completely if you mean to get child element from current context element :

```
By.xpath("./td[2]")
By.xpath("td[2]")
```

Comment: Good, but why mention the first alternative at all?